# Rails 3.1 postgresql shooting blanks into db

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, pgadmin

I'm using postgresql in development for the first time and have successfully installed the binary onto my 10.6 machine. I've created a Rails superuser, `createdb => 'vitae_development'` with this user. It shows up in `$pqsl => '/du'`, but when I key in `/dt`, I get 'no relations'.

My pg gem is pg-0.12.0

In rails 3.10 console, I enter: `User.create!(:name => "Sam", :email => "sam@email.me")`

The resulting output is:

```
INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "name", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Wed, 21 Dec 2011 19:40:13 UTC +00:00], ["email", nil], ["name", nil], ["updated_at", Wed, 21 Dec 2011 19:40:13 UTC +00:00]]
```

That appears to be a bunch of blanks. I've searched the googles but must have missed the right search terms.

pgAdmin3 seems to show the tables in place, as best as I can determine, but with no data that I can find.

This is the relevant snippet from my database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: vitae_development
  username: rails
  password:
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

For completeness, [here's the whole `user.rb`](http://pastie.org/3054620):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :name, :email

  email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :name, :presence => true,
                   :length => { :maximum => 50 }
  validates :email, :presence => true,
                    :format => { :with => email_regex },
                    :uniqueness => { :case_insensitive => false }
end
```

What am I overlooking? I've done `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: What types are email and name in the database? Could you paste in your migration file? (Also, you may want to set :null => false for those columns in your migration file, just as a better safety net.)

Comment: Yes, this is the last two migrations from this a.m.: http://pastie.org/3054381

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you perhaps override the `email` or `email=` methods or put `attr_accessor :email` in your `User.rb` file?

EDIT:
Take out line 2 where it says `attr_accessor :name, :email`. `attr_accessor` in the context of rails is for object variables that won't be saved to the database.

Comment: Hmm. I don't understand how I can override the email methods? This is the entire users.rb file. http://pastie.org/3054620

Comment: Take out line 2 where it says attr_accessor :name, :email. attr_accessor in the context of rails is for object variables that won't be saved to the database.

Comment: You should put your comment into your answer as it is the answer. I added the `user.rb` to the question for context.

Answer (score 0):

Try eliminating the formatting validation on email...if it works I'd take a deeper look at email_regex

Comment: thx. Neither email, nor name show up with values. Here is the command in console after removing the validation on email and restarting the server. http://pastie.org/3054754